# Without it being a come-on

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, content-clauses

I was watching the movie "when harry met sally " and I had a trouble to understand this highlighted part of their conversation.

> Sally: Amanda is my friend.
> Harry: So?
> Sally: So you're going with her.
> Harry: So?
> Sally: So you're coming on to me!
> Harry: No I wasn't. What?

> (Sally is not impressed, jaw drops, wide eyes)

> Harry: Can't a man say a woman is attractive **without it being a come-on?**
> Alright, alright, let's just say just for the sake of argument
> that it was a come-on. What do you want me to do about it? I take
> it back, ok? I take it back.
> Sally: You can't take it back.
> Harry: Why not?
> Sally: Because it's already out there.

Comment: [*come-on*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/come-on): "*countable noun* - A come-on is a gesture or remark which someone, especially a woman, makes in order to encourage another person to make sexual advances to them." or "12. *informal* - 
anything that serves as a lure or enticement"

Answer (score 1):

The word *come-on* is the noun form of the phrasal verb *come on*. In this case, *come on* means "To show sexual or relational interest through words or sometimes actions." ([source](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/come_on))

Basically, Sally interpreted Harry's words and actions as Harry taking sexual interest in her. Harry argues that he only meant it as a compliment, not as a sexual advance.